# How I can create an alias to run xampp on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xampp, console, zsh

Creé ese alias para ejecutar xampp pero esos no muestran nada en la consola, y necesito ver si está ocurriendo un error

```
alias xon='sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start | figlet Xampp Start | lolcat'
alias xoff='sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop | figlet Xampp off | lolcat'
```

¿Cómo puedo modificar esas líneas para que me muestren el error usando un alias para hacerlo más rápido?

Comment: Hola Fredy, esto es SOes, el idioma soportado es el español, te sugiero que traduzcas tu pregunta o la muevas a SO, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Disculpe soy nuevo, como puedo mover?

Comment: Traduci el titulo tambien. No, no podes moverla... podes escribirla en el otro sitio...

Comment: @MarcePuente moverla? como es eso?

Comment: Si quieres preguntar en inglés, ve a [so].

Comment: @gbianchi, Fredy, mover = acto de sacar una cosa de un lugar y ponerla en otro, la sacas de SOes y la pones en SO, nada del otro planeta, pero ya que decidiste traducirla, no tiene sentido.

Comment: Pensaría que los filtros que conectaste con la llamada a `lampp` están limpiando la salida de `lampp`. Qué sucede si los quitas del alias?